# Do duplicate references need significant additional memory in Java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class TestClassA
{
   private Object ref;

   //...constructor, getter, setter
}
```

now let's suppose I do:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
   String S = "test";
   TestInstanceA = new TestClass();
   TestInstanceA.setRef(S);

   TestInstanceB = new TestClass();
   TestInstanceB.setRef(S);
}
```

Is this program going to need twice the memory of the first object, or is java representing it as an (internal) pointer to the same area of memory, meaning not much additional memory is going to be needed?

I always thought that objects in java were basically the same thing as pointers in C (only that they are combined with values), but some of my programs seem to eat increasing amounts of memory, especially when many objects are dynamically created. So I want to make sure I am not getting it wrong.

Excited for your answers!

Comment: It will only store a lightweight reference to a single object.  Note however that since `S` is a string literal, it is interned so it doesn't really behave like an ordinary object.  Further note that the character sequence `test` consumes less memory than a single pointer on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: That means I don't have to fear giving the same huge object hierarchy reference to a thousand different objects?

And yeah I should probably not have used String as an example. 
So you are saying if a copy is cheaper it's not going to use a pointer? Interesting.

Comment: TestInstanceA and TestInstanceB are both objects. Both objects have memory allocated to store their informations. Thus you need memory to have the Object TestInstanceA and the Object TestInstanceB in memory. The String 's' exists only once and both the ref attributes points to that string.

Comment: @BalckEye: okay. That seems like it answered my question (:
I'm kind of happy and say about that. It means I'm closer to solving a problem, but also that I have one hell of optimizing in front of me.
Anyhow; thanks!

Comment: @5gon12eder `"test"` does not take less memory than a pointer. First, each character is two bytes, so 4 characters to represent `"test"` take up exactly 64 bits. Second, a `String` in java is mo re than just the characters it consists of. It contains a pointer to the char array (another 64 bits), and three ints - offset, count and hash (96 bits), plus the char array, has another 32 bit field for length. So, the total amount of memory a string `"test"` occupies in java is `64 + 64 + 96 + 32=256` bits or 32 bytes. This is (4 times) more than a pointer. Plus, note, that you still need a pointer.

Comment: @Dima You are right, I was wrongly estimating the size of `String`.  Nevertheless, the object's size isn't very significant, which is the main point.

Comment: @5gon12eder It is not significant as long as you are talking about one string in a test program. But consider reading a 65K lines files into memory. That requires a megabyte of overhead, having nothing to do with your data. It adds up quickly. Strings aren't that bad actually. Consider an *empty* `HashMap` entry (with no key or value). It requires 44 bytes on a 64 bit machine, not counting the pointer to the entry itself.